# Naming convention for date properties

Tags: c#, datetime, naming, naming-conventions

This is not so much a question but a request for comments.

I've always hated the inclusion of the the **date** in a named property or variable that is a type of date or datetime.  For example:

```
DateTime DateFileOpened {get; set;}
```

To me it seems that I'm including the data type in the variable name.

What I've settled on is a to use the word 'When' in place of date,  For example

```
DateTime WhenFileOpened {get; set;}
```

Generally, I've stolen this from the use of Is or Has in boolean variables/properties.

So the question is:  Does anybody have a better naming convention for dates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I too dislike the redundancy when specifying "Date" in a DateTime variable.

As an alternative you could use:

```
DateTime OpenedOn { get; set; }
```

Naming methods is hard if a reader is unaware of the context; If this method exists in a class used to store properties of a file then:

```
var fileOpenedOn = file.OpenedOn;
```

would read well.

Answer (score 6):

The [MSDN naming conventions for properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provide that the name of the property should be a noun or noun phrase, a criteria that `DateFileOpened` satisfies but `WhenFileOpened` does not.

It can help in these cases to check the property names used by the core .NET framework classes.  The following code will extract the names of all properties of type `DateTime` from all loaded assemblies:

```
foreach (var v in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a=>a.GetTypes())
    .Where(a=>a.IsClass)
    .SelectMany(a=>a.GetProperties())
    .Where(a=>a.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)))
          Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", v.DeclaringType, v.Name);
```

The output shows several conventions in place.

1. `______Date`, `____Time` (Examples: `System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition.CreationDate`, `System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Date`, `System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs.SignalTime`).  The use of `Date` by itself can be confusing when both a date and time can be returned, but `Time` by itself can be considered less ambiguous.  (A property that returns a time without a date would have a return type of `TimeSpan` rather than `DateTime`.)
2. `_____DateTime`, `_____TimeStamp`.  (Examples: `System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.MinSupportedDateTime`, `System.Diagnostics.TraceEventCache.DateTime`, `System.Net.Cookie.Timestamp`).  This convention is verbose, but it is unambiguous that the entire timestamp (Date+Time) is intended.
3. Neither.  (Examples: `System.Net.FtpWebResponse.LastModified`, `System.Globalization.DaylightTime.Start`, `System.Net.Cookie.Expires`).  Not including the return type in the name is consistent with most property names (`String.Length`, not `String.LengthInt`).

Since there is no consistent approach, any of these patterns may be deemed acceptable.

As a matter of preference, however, `DateFileOpened` suggests that a file can only be opened once.  If this is not the case, a property name like `FileLastOpened` or even simply `LastOpened` could imply a `DateTime` return type without including the return type in the property name.  If it cannot be avoided, then a name like `FileOpenedTime` is consistent with the .NET guidelines, consistent with Framework property names, and unambiguous.

Comment: `Expires` is such a misleading name though (on the `Cookie` example there)… It could be read as a `bool` property too from the outside.

Answer (score -5):

I generally use "date_" as a prefix:

```
date_created
date_end
date_deleted
date_modified
```

Then You can put naming convention for date as "date_FileOpened"